# Covariance of states of a finite Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I know it is possible to construct a covariance matrix for states of a Markov chain but I cannot seem to find a proper way to compute it. I will attach some theories I found from Kemeny and Snell's FMCs which states about limiting covariance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I just cannot understand how the covariance matrix can be generated using this. I need to know whether there is a much easier way to approach this problem. In the same text in an example the have computed the convariance matrix without any steps showing how it was computed. 
[image]

Hope someone could help me out on this and give me a better insight to the concept of covarince with respect to states in a Markov chain. Thanks !

Answer (score -3):

Try this (R code) 
   a <- A[1,]   # Limiting matrix
   C <- mat.or.vec(m,m)  # mxm covariance matrix
   delta <- function(i,j)  {delta <- 0; if (i==j) delta <- 1; return(delta)}
   for (i in 1:m)   {
      for (j in 1:m)   {
         C[i,j] <- a[i]*Z[i,j]+a[j]*Z[j,i] - a[i]*a[j] - a[i]*delta(i,j)
      }
   }
Result:

> 375*C
>        [,1] [,2] [,3]
>   [1,]  134  -18 -116
>   [2,]  -18   36  -18
>   [3,] -116  -18  134
>   Kemeny's example on page 89.