# Can we find a correlation between states of a Markov chain?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a fair bit of knowledge on Markov chains but I recently wondered if there is a way to find out a correlation between the states of a finite Markov chain. I could not find any material on this. intuitively I feel a given state must be negatively correlated with the other states since more the system is in another state the less it will be in that state. However I do not know any proper theories behind it. Hope someone could help me out. Thanks.

Adding more to this, what I need to know is whether we can figure out if the states are linearly related or not. If we consider a particular vector, then is there a possibility of getting a vector of correlations between that particular state of the MC with the rest of the states. I guess the correlations may change over the transitions but I cannot say for sure. As I said before I do not have any theories to add to this to improve my answer hope this clears out any doubts. Thanks again

Comment: Please define "correlation between the states".

Comment: @Did I added some more explanation to the question hope it helps

Comment: You still did not define what you call correlation between the states. For a Markov chain on the states $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ with transition matrix $Q$, what would be the correlation between states $1$ and $2$?

Comment: @Did As I said, I want to check if there is a linear relationship  between the states. One thing I missed was, to talk about a correlation the covariance should be found between the given states (if it can be found that is). If you are asking for any formula I do not have one that maybe a suitable for this. Like we use Pearson's Correlation Coeffient to check the linear dependence can't we do something similar to the states as well?

Comment: The states are just... states. If the state space is {black,white,red}, how do you define the correlation between black and red? Note that correlations mean numbers and that black and red are not numbers. (Unless this time you respond, this is my last try to transform this post into a real question.)

Comment: @DonaldEdwards http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960831/covariance-of-states-of-a-finite-markov-chain maybe the theorems and reference in this will help

Comment: @Did I don't know whether what the OP is asking is the same as what I have asked in the link above. Maybe something meaningful can be taken out of it to construct a better answer

Comment: @Did What if we do this. Consider a particular state. Then observe the probabilities of going into another state over few transition periods. So we kind of have few data point. Let $v_1=(p_{i1},p_{i2},...,p_{iN})$. Then after n transitions we can have $v_n=(p_{i1}^n,...,p_{iN}^n)$. Maybe compare these and get a correlation?

Comment: @Heisenberg Interesting suggestion, but I fear this is quite unrelated to the words actually used by the OP.

Comment: @Heisenberg I think your suggestion is brilliant.

Comment: @did Heisenberg's method of getting set of vectors and then using them to build up a correlation vector is will work for me. I think Heisenberg's thinking is in line with mine sorry if I had explained it poorly. Maybe we could build up on that to come up with something meaningful?

Comment: @DonaldEdwards Thankyou but it was a wild guess without much thinking. However even I am not sure how to take this forward from there. Hope Did can help

Comment: @Heisenberg, wouldn't a correlation between the states of a Markov chain simply show that the chain has not reached stationarity yet? Wouldn't you need to put those pairings in a multiple set of scenarios as well?

Comment: It is possible, but in specific types of states. Please refer to Fredkin et al. 1985.